# Is there a way to avoid joining same table for new condition?

Tags: sql

I have a table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | Canada |
| 933 | US |

Then I have a table that I need to join this table to

| Customer | CurrentTerritory | NewTerritory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03AA42242d | Canada | US |

Eventually I need to get id for both Canada and US.
Is there a way to do it without doing

```
 MainTable mt JOIN Territoryinfo ti on mt.CurrentTerritory = ti.Name
JOIN Territoryinfo ti on mt.NewTerritory = ti.Name
```

same table join ?

Comment: why don't you want to join? what do you want instead?

Comment: because it slows down the query. I just assume I may not be  very experienced in SQL and  there is a possibility of lack of knowledge on this case.

Comment: @twmp . . . In a reasonably designed database, two joins would be the fastest method.